# TypeScript - error: cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: typescript

I have identified a problem when using intersection types in TypeScript...

I have three type aliases:

- `Prototype<T>` - expresses an object/class that has a `prototype` property.
- `DefaultCtor<T>` - expresses an object/class with a default constructor.
- `ParameterizedCtor<T>` expresses an object/class with a parameterized constructor.

I have tried these intersection permutations:

- `Prototype<T> & DefaultCtor<T>` - works fine.
- `Prototype<T> & ParameterizedCtor<T>` - raises a compiler error.

**Example**

```
type Prototype<T> = {
    prototype: T;
}

type DefaultCtor<T> = {
    new(): T;
}

type ParameterizedCtor<T> = {
    new(...args: any[]): T
}

function makeDefault<T>(ctor: Prototype<T> & DefaultCtor<T>): T {
    return new ctor();
}

function makeWithArgs<T>(ctor: Prototype<T> & ParameterizedCtor<T>, ...args: any[]): T {
    return new ctor(...args);
    // ERROR: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
}
```

Try it in the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Prototype%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prototype%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20DefaultCtor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new()%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ParameterizedCtor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makeDefault%3CT%3E(ctor%3A%20Prototype%3CT%3E%20%26%20DefaultCtor%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ctor()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makeWithArgs%3CT%3E(ctor%3A%20Prototype%3CT%3E%20%26%20ParameterizedCtor%3CT%3E%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ctor(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%20Cannot%20use%20'new'%20with%20an%20expression%20whose%20type%20lacks%20a%20call%20or%20construct%20signature.%0D%0A%7D)

**Error**
The error occurs with the `Prototype<T> & ParameterizedCtor<T>` intersection:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or
>   construct signature.

Why does the TypeScript compiler recognise the `Prototype<T> & DefaultCtor<T>` intersection type as having a constructor, but not the `Prototype<T> & ParameterizedCtor<T>` intersection type?

Comment: Using `ParameterizedCtor` on its own works as well.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, I meant to add that to the post. Good spot!

Comment: Maybe it's a bug, seems odd.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, I think so too. I think this will need the attention of the TypeScript language team.

Comment: @H.B. Found a workaround for now...check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround**

In some edge cases using a cast will provide an interim solution while the TypeScript team come up with a fix.

**Example**

```
function make<T>(ctor: Prototype<T> & ParameterizedCtor<T>, ...args: any[]): T {
    console.log(ctor.prototype);
    return new (ctor as ParameterizedCtor<T>)(...args);
}
```

Comment: Well, you could always just `any` cast XD

Comment: @H.B. You could, but that seems a little foolhardy.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a known bug, filed at [Microsoft/TypeScript#17388](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17388), reported in July of 2017.  It is slated to be fixed for TypeScript v2.9, but the history of the issue looks like the fix version has been pushed back a few times.  Go there and  if you feel so inclined, I guess?  Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: I've escalated this with them. Thanks!